# How to get y_train in model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For some reason I need to use y_train (the target) in my model (not only in loss function), but I didn't find a way to get it.

I get my training dataset like this:

```
  train_ds = DataGenerator("train", args).fetch()

  <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((2, None), (2, 4000, 22)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

The second part (2,4000,22) is the target. Then I fit the model:

```
  history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, callbacks=callbacks, 
  batch_size=args.batch_size, epochs=args.max_epoch)
```

I know how to get the target separately outside the model. But inside the model I don't know how. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

The DataGenerator class contains X,y as variables and batches. Internally the *getitem*_(self, index): returns the X,y batches for the model. The *getitem*_ calls the _data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp) method which generators the X,y data.

```
 training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, 
 **params)
 validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, 
 **params)

 model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                use_multiprocessing=True,
                workers=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I just find some ways to solve this.

1. Use tf.concat() to concatenate the data in y_train to x_train and
   send them together into the model, them separate them. But the
   dimension of both thing should be the same. (My input and target
   don't have the same size so I didn't try this.)
2. Use two inputs like this:

   ```
   model.fit((x_train,y_train),y_train)
   ```

Hope this can help somehow :)